# How do you connect and disconnect a quick release chain link?

Tags: maintenance, chain, terminology, reference, master-link

I can't find any nice video or pictures tutorial that explains how to connect and disconnect a *quick release chain link*. Am I not finding anything because it has another more common name?

How do you connect and disconnect a quick release chain link?

Comment: I accepted moz's answer for a chronological reason.

Comment: How to open: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45958/how-do-i-open-a-master-link-in-a-chain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're more commonly called [master link](http://www.google.com/search?q=chain%20master%20link)s and sites like the [Park Tool](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-installation-derailleur-bikes) one have detailed instructions.

If you can edit in more detailed questions about the actual problems you're having that would help.

From the Park Tool Website:

> Some chain manufacturers offer a "master-link" to join the chain. Be sure to read the manufacturers directions. Typically, the bicycle chain ends must have inner plates on each end. In other words, neither chain end has an outer plate with a rivet. The link comes in two pieces.
>
> [image: Master link halves on a chain before connecting]
>
> Install one piece through inside face of chain, and install second piece through outside of the other chain end. Engage the two pieces so link rivet mates to link plate hole. Pull chain to lock the link. The best method to do this is to move master link to top section between rear cogs and front chainrings and press hard on pedals. This insures the link is fully locked. Inspect link before riding the chain.
>
> [image: Master link on a chain]
>
> Note: Some master links are reusable, while others are disposable and should be replaced after each removal. Check manufacturer's specifications.

Comment: I looked at the videos that you and Neil linked and it looks like I am doing things correctly. If I am having hard time removing the chain, then I guess it's because my chain is too tight (see my other question http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/4141/1621).

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is also called a [master link](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4483#4483) chain. A search on Youtube brings up several videos:

Comment: that's the keyword I was missing. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure I follow the question, but if you're looking to take a chain the currently does not have a qr link and add one, you'll need a chain link tool to first remove one of the links in your chain. You do this by lining up the pin pushing part on a pin and then cranking it until the pin is all the way out. Do the same on the other side, so one complete link is out. Now put the qr link in that spot and slide the side of the link that as the "c" part down over the pins. the open part of the link will pinch one of the pins in a little grove.

If you look at the site you sent's pix while reading this, I hope it makes more sense. Good luck.