How do I attach this master link on the chain?
This is a master link with PYC brand. I couldn't figure out how to attach it on my chain as both pins are on the same side. Can you help me out? Also can you tell me for which speed this master link is? 

Not a duplicate, but there's a whole lot of master link info already at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45958/how-do-i-open-a-master-link-in-a-chain/

These master links require using the chain as a lever on either end to subtly bend the link, and press the plate on with your thumbs.
The risk of using force with pliers is that it may damage the retention mechanism, allowing the plate to come off and surprise you by dropping the chain completely.

I had one of those installed by a bike shop on my recumbent trike with 3 x 9 gearing, so if yours is the same it is for 8 or 9 speed chain, not for 11 speed.
Installing them requires a special tool or being handy as you need to pull the two pins towards each other while you place the plate.
The bike shop had not done that right so I had to do that, since I have bought the kind with a pin each side, easier to install and less likely to be installed wrong.

My friend came for help and he actually managed to install it. First he clipped in one of the pins and the outer plate. After that he aligned the other pin and the hole on the outer plate and clipped them together by forcing with pliers.

So your friend is handy or knowledgeable and did manage without the special tool I was told about.

just a note: you can get those (and most if not all other) kinds of master links for all kinds of chain widths.
